# tkzKiviatGrad skip number

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-kiviat

I am writing up a paper that has bipolar results ranging from -3 to 3 but excluding 0. How can I skip it. I am already using something in the preamble to shift the numbers down three to achieve -3 start.
MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tkz-kiviat}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikzscale}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\makeatletter
\def\tkzKiviatGrad{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\tkz@KiviatGrad}{\tkz@KiviatGrad[]}} 
\def\tkz@KiviatGrad[#1](#2){% 
\begingroup
\pgfkeys{/kiviatgrad/.cd,
graduation distance= 0 pt,
prefix ={},
suffix={},
unity=1
 }
 \pgfqkeys{/kiviatgrad}{#1}% 
\let\tikz@label@distance@tmp\tikz@label@distance
\global\let\tikz@label@distance\tkz@kiv@grad
 \foreach \nv in {0,...,\tkz@kiv@lattice}{ %original: \foreach \nv in {1,...,\tkz@kiv@lattice}{
 \pgfmathparse{\tkz@kiv@unity*\nv} 
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\result}{\pgfmathresult-3} %original: \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\result}{\pgfmathresult}
 \protected@edef\tkz@kiv@gd{\tkz@kiv@prefix$\result$\tkz@kiv@suffix}
    \path[/kiviatgrad/.cd,#1] (0:0)--(360/\tkz@kiv@radial*#2:\nv*\tkz@kiv@gap) 
       node[label=(360/\tkz@kiv@radial*#2)-90:\tkz@kiv@gd] {}; 
      }
 \let\tikz@label@distance\tikz@label@distance@tmp  
\endgroup
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=45]
    \tkzKiviatDiagram[scale=.6,label distance=.5cm, radial=5,
    gap=1, lattice=5,label space=2.5]{Vulnerability to erosion,Vulnerability to overtopping,Aesthetic value,Ease of beach access,Safety factor,Lifespan,Disruption to local residents during construction,Disruption to natural coastal processed and habitats}
    \tkzKiviatLine[ultra thick,color=red,mark=none,fill=red,opacity=.2](0,2,3,4,5,5,4,2)
    \tkzKiviatGrad[unity=1](0)
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Kiviat chart showing the evaluation of rip rap as a management strategy}
    \label{fig:radar_rr}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you mean by "skip 0"?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-kiviat}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\makeatletter
\def\tkzKiviatGrad{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\tkz@KiviatGrad}{\tkz@KiviatGrad[]}} 
\def\tkz@KiviatGrad[#1](#2){% 
\begingroup
\pgfkeys{/kiviatgrad/.cd,
graduation distance= 0 pt,
prefix ={},
suffix={},
unity=1
 }
 \pgfqkeys{/kiviatgrad}{#1}% 
\let\tikz@label@distance@tmp\tikz@label@distance
\global\let\tikz@label@distance\tkz@kiv@grad
 \foreach \nv in {0,...,\tkz@kiv@lattice}{ %original: \foreach \nv in {1,...,\tkz@kiv@lattice}{ %}
 \pgfmathparse{\tkz@kiv@unity*\nv} 
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\result}{ifthenelse(\pgfmathresult<3,\pgfmathresult-3,\pgfmathresult-2)} %original: \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\result}{\pgfmathresult}
 \protected@edef\tkz@kiv@gd{\tkz@kiv@prefix$\result$\tkz@kiv@suffix}
    \path[/kiviatgrad/.cd,#1] (0:0)--(360/\tkz@kiv@radial*#2:\nv*\tkz@kiv@gap) 
       node[label=(360/\tkz@kiv@radial*#2)-90:\tkz@kiv@gd] {}; 
      }
 \let\tikz@label@distance\tikz@label@distance@tmp  
\endgroup
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=45]
    \tkzKiviatDiagram[scale=.6,label distance=.5cm, radial=5,
    gap=1, lattice=5,label space=2.5]{Vulnerability to erosion,Vulnerability to overtopping,Aesthetic value,Ease of beach access,Safety factor,Lifespan,Disruption to local residents during construction,Disruption to natural coastal processed and habitats}
    \tkzKiviatLine[ultra thick,color=red,mark=none,fill=red,opacity=.2](0,2,3,4,5,5,4,2)
    \tkzKiviatGrad[unity=1](0)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]